# Is it normal for airport to transmit unmodulated carrier on its ATIS frequency for extended periods of time?

Tags: radio, atis

So I'm around 4 km away from the [City-Airport Mannheim (EDFM/MHG)](https://skyvector.com/airport/EDFM/Mannheim-City-Airport). Various websites tell me that its ATIS frequency is 136.550 MHz.

When I tune to 136.550 with my VHF AM receiver, I can see a strong carrier, with no modulation at all. I've listened to it for several hours, on different weekdays and during different times of day.

So my question is: Is this usual behavior or not? I'm aware that the airport in question doesn't see much traffic, but I'd sort of expect the ATIS to be either running, when needed, or switched-off, when not needed.

Comment: @mins Yes, the receiver is in AM mode (only settings it has in this band are 25 kHz step or 8.33 kHz step) and I can hear both ATC and aircraft on other frequencies. Right now, I'm listening to 126.325 MHz and 123.275 MHz and I can hear both ATC and aircraft fine on them. Also, I couldn't find to whom are those frequencies assigned on many websites I've seen. Is there another frequency change in  progress?

Comment: @mins No, but on the other side, there's very little local traffic. I can mostly hear planes going to the Frankfurt (and they report their ATIS). I did hear activity on the MHG tower frequency a couple of times, but I haven't hear any of them report ATIS information yet. Basically, I don't have enough information to conclude if they're actually reporting ATIS or not.

Comment: You'll find frequencies and hours in this [AIS documentation](https://www.pilotundflugzeug.de/img/ud/2017/01/30/16/5714410/010524-AIP_EDFM.pdf) at section 2.18